# Equivalence of columns spaces

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, vectors

Assuming we have matrix B as follows:
$$ B=\begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1n}\\
b_{21}&\cdots&b_{2n}\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots\\
b_{n1}&\cdots&b_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}$$
I want to verify the space spanned by columns of B ,n$\times$n matrix, is equivalent to the space spanned by column of A ,a m$\times$ m matrix as follows:
$$A= \begin{bmatrix}
b_{11}&\cdots&b_{1n}&0&0...&0\\
b_{21}&\cdots&b_{2n}&0&0...&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&\vdots&0&0...&0\\
b_{n1}&\cdots&b_{nn}&0&0...&0\\
0&\cdots&0&1&0&...&0\\
0&\cdots&0&0&1&...&0\\
\vdots&\vdots&...&&&\vdots\\
0&\cdots&0&0&0&...&1\\
\end{bmatrix}$$
I cannot see any reasons to contradict my assumption(Since the the dimension of column vectors of A and B are not the same I was not sure).

Could anyone help please?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The column space of $A,B$ lie in spaces of different dimensions. You have $\operatorname{rk} A = \operatorname{rk} B + (m-n)$.

Comment: I don't know what that means.

Comment: I thought may be there is a way to compare the column span of two matrix with different number of rows. (Like in calculus we transfer the representation of a point in 2D to 3D)

Comment: I really don't know what you are trying to do.

Comment: sorry for confusion. I guess I have something in my head that I cannot explain well. Thanks.

Comment: By including all of those $1$s along the main diagonal of the larger matrix, you’ve increased the dimension of the column space, so the two column spaces can’t be isomorphic. It’s not clear what other notion of “equivalent” you might have in mind.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. From the comments I concluded the way I look at problem is not making sense. I thought we can assume a particular space can be explained using column spaces of matrices that have different numbers of rows. Like in calculus, when I assumed  $x=\left(2,3\right) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is equivalent to  $y=\left (2,3,t \right) \in \mathbb{R}^3$and t is a constant. Now I think my assumptions are not correct.
Sorry if I caused confusions.

Comment: @Crimson It would be more like the “equivalence” of the line $t(2,3)$ with the line $t(2,3,0)$. Vector spaces must include the origin.

Comment: I see. Probably for this case I need to keep the extra rows and delete extra columns that I added in matrix A. Although I am not sure  doing this is common or making sense in linear algebra.